# zeros of a vector-valued function

Tags: matlab, function, vector, zero, minimize

Is there any function in MATLAB that can find the zeros of a vector-valued function? The commonly used function `fzero` is just for scalar functions and also cannot find the zeros of any scalar function such as `f(x)=x^2`.

Comment: To clarify, is this a set of independent equations that you wish to solve together (normally done with `fzero` and a `for` loop) or is this a multivariable equation (these don't generally have well-defined roots and must be solved with optimization techniques, e.g., `fsolve`)?

Comment: It's a set of multivariable equations; these equations are independent.

Comment: Try `fsolve`. Can't say more without a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's optimization toolbox has the [fsolve method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) that states it is capable of:

> Solves a problem specified by `F(x) = 0` for `x`, where `F(x)` is a function that returns a **vector value**. x is a vector or a matrix.

Otherwise, finding zeroes of a generic vector valued function can be done by attempting to minimize the norm of the vectorial output. Lets assume your function `F(x)` outputs an `Nx1` vector. You could attempt to find the zero by doing the following:

```
 y = fminunc(@(x) sum(F(x).^2));
```

or

```
 y = fminsearch(@(x) sum(F(x).^2));
```

You would then have to check if the returned `y` is "sufficiently close" to zero.

One last comment, the `fzero` function's algorithm determines the existence of roots by checking for sign changes. The [docs] explicitly say that

> `x = fzero(fun,x0)` tries to find a point `x` where `fun(x) = 0`. This solution is where `fun(x)` changes sign. `fzero` cannot find a root of a function such as `x^2`.

In fact, in older versions of matlab (R2012b) the `fzero`'s doc had a section with its limitations that said

> The fzero command finds a point where the function changes sign. If the function is continuous, this is also a point where the function has a value near zero. If the function is not continuous, fzero may return values that are discontinuous points instead of zeros. For example, fzero(@tan,1) returns 1.5708, a discontinuous point in tan.
>
> Furthermore, the fzero command defines a zero as a point where the function crosses the x-axis. Points where the function touches, but does not cross, the x-axis are not valid zeros. For example, y = x.^2 is a parabola that touches the x-axis at 0. Because the function never crosses the x-axis, however, no zero is found. For functions with no valid zeros, fzero executes until Inf, NaN, or a complex value is detected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just have one more question. If the system of nonlinear equations admits more than one solution; how can we find all of them. A typical way is to run the `fsolve(f,x0)` on a grid of initial guesses. But is there a better (more efficient) way to find them?

Comment: @SaraWinslet, I'm not aware of other, more efficient, methods besides what you said to find more than one solution. And even using a grid of initial guesses does not guarantee that you will find all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand something in your question, but you can try this solution:

```
y = @(x) x^2;

fminbnd(y, -100, 100)

ans =   -3.5527e-15
```

And maybe you can try `solve`:

```
syms x y
y = @(x) x^2;
solve( y==0, x);
```

Can't check it right now, I will edit this solution a little bit later.

Comment: I have a set of equations, not just one equation.